# JavaFX 2 Scene switch

Tags: java, javafx

I am programming a login screen with JavaFX 2. It looks pretty well with the oracle documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/form.htm

But I would like to add a button "Register" that changes the scene with the same window.

I tried with "pane.setVisible(value);" but that didn't work

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a Scene from another method or create a Scene within the "Start", and set the Scene on stage. For example:

```
public static Scene secondScene(final Stage primaryStage){
     BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
     Label l = new Label("Second Scene");
     pane.setCenter(l);

      //let's say I have a button that changes back to original stage
     Button b = new Button("Main stage");  
     b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
     public void handle(ActionEvent t){
           // create your own Scene and then set it to primaryStage
          primaryStage.setScene(new Scene ... );
     }
     });

     return new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
}
```

Then on your start method:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
Button b = new Button("Register");
mainPane.setCenter(b);

b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
     public void handle(ActionEvent t){
          primaryStage.setScene(secondScene(primaryStage));
     }
});

  primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane, 300,300));
  primaryStage.show();
}
```

This will change to "SecondScene" when the button is pressed.

EDIT ////////////////////////////////////////
BASICALLY:

you need to pass in primaryStage as an argument to SecondScene in order to set another Scene onto it.
What you could do in this case is, make a method that outputs the main scene and then set it using that.

```
public static Scene mainScene(final Stage primaryStage){
     .....
     return new Scene(...);
}
```

Comment: thank you :) that is already very useful,
but how do I then change back to the first scene? :o
because I  can't use "primaryStage.setScene(secondScene);"
because it is an unknown variable

Comment: if it helped you, pressed the check mark :)